# Bootstrap from Twitter IE7 bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a bug in a site that i have created in IE7.

URL of the site: http://moldipaints-dokkum.nl/productcontroller/getProductList/19

When opening a product in IE7 the bootstrap modal is behind the page and the grey overlay is on top. and images are on top of modal.

I changed the following:

css position : relative/absolute/fixed (Only modal is not showing correctly)

css z-index : (Not any difference)

Potential fix Twitter (Github) ; http://jsfiddle.net/ATeaH/8/

None of these are correct. What can i do to make this work?

**Update Code from project**

Page rendering

```
    <?php
    if(isset($productByType)){
        $countwidth = (count($productByType) / 2)*260+100;
    }?>



    <div class="productView">
        <div class="aligndiv">
           <div class="productcenter">
               <div class="productenview">
                   <div class="productcontainer" style="width:<?=@$countwidth?>px;" >
                       <?php
                       if(!empty($productByType)){
                       for($i=0;$i < count($productByType); $i++){

                       $id = $productByType[$i]['id'];
                       $title = $productByType[$i]['title'];
                       $img = base_url('/img/producten/'.$productByType[$i]["img"]);

                       if($i % 2 == 0){
                          echo '<div class="seperatorforproduct">';
                       //0,2,4,6,8
                       }

                    echo '<div class="button btnstyle">';
                    echo '<div class="imgbtn">';    
                    //  <!-- afbeelding -->
                    echo '<img src="'.$img.'" title="'.$title.'" alt="'.$title.'" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal'.$id.'" />';
                    echo '</div>';  
                    echo '<div class="txtbtn txtstyle">';   
                    echo '<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal'.$id.'" >'.$title.'</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    ?>
                    <div class="modal" style="display:none;" id="modal<?=$id?>">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                            <h2><?=$title?></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="modal-left">
                            <img src="<?=$img?>" title="<?=$title?>" alt="<?=$title?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-right">
                            <p><?=$productByType[$i]['info']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            Neem contact op met Moldipaints-Dokkum.nl voor meer informatie, telefoonnummer: 0519-297409
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                    if($i % 2 == 1 || $i == count($productByType)){
                        // 0,3,6,9,12
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }      
            }?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Bootstrap

```
    .modal-backdrop {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #000000;
    }
    .modal {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 1000;
      min-height: 500px;
      width: 700px;
      margin: -275px -380px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      *border: 1px solid #999;
      /* IE6-7 */

      -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
      -moz-border-radius: 6px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      }
```

CSS style project

```
    /*   Producten   */
    .productView{position:absolute; width:100%; height:700px; top:50px; margin:auto;}
    .aligndiv{position:relative; width:1024px; margin:auto;}
    .productcenter{width:1024px; height:500px; margin:auto;}
    .productenview{position:relative; width:480px; height: 600px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; float:left; left:10%; margin:auto; margin-right:300px}
    .productcontainer{height: 400px; margin-top:90px; z-index:0;}
    .productmenu{position:absolute; width:300px; top:100px; right:5%; z-index:0;}
    .seperatorforproduct{position:relative; width:240px; height:480px; float:left;}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I just fixed it with another modal. Thanks for you're time. For reference: http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept so others know its solved :)

Comment: You're right. Because i didn't get bootstrap right, i switch to another modal. The version i used was from http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial This is a jquery modal alternative, which is fully customisable. This modal is working perfect in IE7+

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem with the modal popup in IE7.  The modal dialog was displayed beneath the modal backdrop.  However, adding this javascript DID fix the problem for me:

```
$('.fixedVersion .modal').appendTo($("body"));
```

more detail here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ATeaH/8/

Comment: Thanks for the great idea and comprehensive fiddle :D

Comment: I can't take credit for the fiddle, the link was in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and ended up fixing the issue by 1) making sure all my modal dialogs were **not** nested need in the HTML hierarchy, but instead on the root level (right inside `<body>`) and 2) at the end of the HTML document.

The two above conditions may be a bit overkill, but it fixed the issue for me.